# Converting Core PHP code to be compatible with Laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli, laravel-8

How can I convert the following code to be compatible with Laravel 8.

I am trying to output the result of a MYSQL dynamic pivot on a Laravel , how can I optimize or change the core PHP code below so that it becomes compatible with Laravel?

```
$db=mysqli_connect($databasehost,$databaseuser,$databasepass,$databasename) or die ("Connection failed!");
$result = $db->multi_query($sql);

if ($err=mysqli_error($db)) { echo $err."<br><hr>"; }

if ($result) {
  do {
  if ($res = $db->store_result()) {
      echo "<table width=100% border=0><tr>";

      // printing table headers
      for($i=0; $i<mysqli_num_fields($res); $i++)
      {
          $field = mysqli_fetch_field($res);
          echo "<td bgcolor=lightgray><b>{$field->name}</b></td>";
      }
      echo "</tr>\n";

      // printing table rows
      while($row = $res->fetch_row())
      {
          echo "<tr>";
          foreach($row as $cell) {
            if ($cell === NULL) { $cell = '(null)'; }
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";
          }
          echo "</tr>\n";
      }
      $res->free();
      echo "</table>";

    }
  } while ($db->more_results() && $db->next_result());
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: Please edit your post an tell us what error you are getting.

Comment: all you need is $sql. Just take it and put in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

First off if you don't know where to start with this I'd highly recommend you do some more reading of the Laravel documentation or completely some basic tutorials or quick starts to get going. What you're asking isn't something that can necessarily be answered as Laravel is an entire framework that has different sensibilities about how to approach tasks. You don't just "convert code to Laravel" as if it was some other programming language where you need to change some of the reserved words to make a for(...) loop function.

That said to help you in a direction... Most generic php code will function just fine within Laravel. Intermixing the two can be handy at times, tricky in other, and downright dangerous at other times. So really think through exactly what you're trying to accomplish and what should be left as native functionality vs framework supported functions.

That said it seems like what you're going for here is effectively some code which queries the database and then outputs that data formatted into certain HTML elements based on the content of that data.

Laravel through their [model-view-controller style architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) would typically handle it as follows:

1. Create a [Laravel Eloquent Model](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent) that corresponds to your existing database table so that you can query data from it.
2. [Create a controller](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers) (or [possibly a provider](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/providers) depending on how extensible this needs to be) to handle the manipulation of your data before passing it to a view. [Laravel structures all queried data into collections](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections) which have their own host of functions predefined.
3. Pass all the data to from your controller into a [view](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/views) which will allow you to render html elements based on the content of your collections.